# Constructing a positive sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n$ be a sequence such that $a_n>0$ for all $n$. I would like to construct a sequence such that 
$$
\lim_{k\to +\infty}\frac{(\sum_{j=1}^{k}2^ja_j)(\sum_{j=1}^{k}2^ja_j^{-1})}{(\sum_{j=1}^{k}2^j)^2}=\infty.
$$
Note that by the holder inequality we have $\frac{(\sum_{j=1}^{k}2^ja_j)(\sum_{j=1}^{k}2^ja_j^{-1})}{(\sum_{j=1}^{k}2^j)^2}\geq 1$. But i don't know : is there a sequence $a_n$ satisfying $\frac{(\sum_{j=1}^{k}2^ja_j)(\sum_{j=1}^{k}2^ja_j^{-1})}{(\sum_{j=1}^{k}2^j)^2}$ unbounded from above.

Comment: suppose you set $a_j = \left( \sum_{i=1}^j 2^i \right)^2$, I think this would do.

Comment: In fact you can go even simpler: $a_n := 2^n$.

Comment: can you explain carefully to me ? I just already computed, but i haven't seen that the example do it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n := 2^n$. Then by the formula for geometric series $(\ast)$, we get

**1)** $$\sum_{j=1}^k 2^j a_j = \sum_{j=1}^k 4^j \stackrel \ast =  \frac {4^k-1}{4-1}=\frac {4^k-1}3,$$

**2)** $$\left(\sum_{j=1}^k 2^j\right)^2 \stackrel \ast = \left(\frac{2^k-1}{2-1}\right)^2=(2^k - 1)^2.$$

Also,

**3)** $$ \sum_{j=1}^k 2^j a_j^{\,-1} = \sum_{j=1}^k 1 = k.$$

Putting these together, your expression simplifies to:

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\frac {4^k-1}{3(2^k - 1)^2}k \right)= \lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\frac {\left(1-\frac 1 {4^k}\right)}{3\left(1 - \frac 1 {2^k}\right)^2}k \right) = \infty,$$

because the fraction converges to $1/3$, for big enough $k$, it will be greater than $1/4$, say. So your expression in $k$ is eventually bounded below by $k/4$, so it blows up!

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: No worries! You're welcome